# Results coming on main thread, but not on background thread

Tags: iphone, ios

I am making a call to a service from a main thread, and getting the results. But when the same call is made from background, i am not getting results. Any thoughts?

Here is my code :

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,
                                             (unsigned long)NULL), ^(void) {
        self.pathRequest = [[PathRequest alloc] initWithUserId:[userInfobase userId]

        self.pathRequest.target = self;
        self.pathRequest.successSelector = @selector(success:);
        self.pathRequest.errorSelector = @selector(failure:);
        [self.pathRequest execute];
    });
```

In my class PathRequest, i have defined delegate methods for handling server response

```
 - (void) execute
{    
     [restClient loadData:@"/path"];
}

- (void)restClient: (AFRestClient *) client loadedData: (AFMetaData *) metadata { 
}
```

Comment: Please include your code. That'll help us to help you better.

Answer (score 0):

Run the run loop so that `NSConnection` works

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,
                                         (unsigned long)NULL), ^(void) {
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];
    self.pathRequest = [[PathRequest alloc] initWithUserId:[userInfobase userId]

    self.pathRequest.target = self;
    self.pathRequest.successSelector = @selector(success:);
    self.pathRequest.errorSelector = @selector(failure:);
    [self.pathRequest execute];
});
```

Comment: i tried, its not working. I notice that the thread is exiting. I am getting NSThreadWillExitNotification notification.

Comment: Try `performSelectorInBackground:withObject:` and see if that is working

Comment: I am using it - 
            [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(getUserIdsInfoBase:) withObject:[listOfAccounts valueForKey:@"infoBase"]];

Comment: No, its not working.
I am calling the method in background (using performSelectorInBackground), and before making the request i am adding[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run], as u mentioned.

Comment: then I'm afraid my friend that there is some other problem then.. :(

Comment: The problem is most likely that the rest client is setup to integrate with the run loop of the thread that it is on.  Since this is a dispatch operation, that thread will be reclaimed by the system at some point, probably before the operation is finished.  Aren't there any async operations in the rest client?